# Is there such a thing as a reverse dictionary?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-usage

Is there any tool online that generally permits me to enter a phrase or idea and get back a word that means something similar? For example, if I were looking for a better word or phrase for *arguing winsomely but forcefully in favor of something*, where might I go to find such a definition?

Comment: Perhaps the tags ([tag:online-resources]) or ([tag:dictionaries]) (or both) might be suitable for this question? (I did not make an edit suggestion, since I am not that familiar with tagging system at this site.)

Comment: A straightforward thesaurus, used imaginatively, can often help.

Comment: Agreed @WS2 I find a thesaurus obliquely useful.  I never ever find the word I'm looking for in there, but after following several synonym rabbit holes and giving up in frustration, then the word comes to mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes -- try [OneLook's reverse dictionary.](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml)